# POWER BI sum of total with slicer

Tags: powerbi, measure

I want to create a measure that will count all of my orders which depend on date slicer. I've got a table with orders between 2023-01-01 and 2023-02-28 with an attribiute which indicates that the order amount is greater then 100 or less then 100.

I've created a measure, that count all of orders, but when I add a slicer in which I can choose the period, this measure doesn't depend on it. Examples below.

Full Table
[image: Full Table]

Uncorrect Matrix with my measure and date between 2023-01-01 and 2023-01-31
[image: Uncorrect Matrix with my measure and date between 2023-01-01 and 2023-01-31]

Correct Matrix with date between 2023-01-01 and 2023-01-31
[image: Correct Matrix with date between 2023-01-01 and 2023-01-31]

My measure:

OrdersCount= COUNTX(all('Orders'),
'Orders'[OrderID])

Sorry for my english, but it's not my primary language and i hope everything what i wrote is clear:)

Comment: Could you please add the metric formula you created

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by myself. I've selected data to another table using summarize and linked it with date slicer. After that I've created a measure that counts all orders in the new table and after adding the new measure to the matrix it works fine. I'm newbie in PBI so it wasn't simple for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this formula,

```
Total_Count = calculate('datasetname'[OrderID]),ALL(datasetname))
```

Or may be you can try creating a measure using Quick Measure option. Select 'Total for Category(Filters not applied)' and add necessary fields and change aggregation as needed.

Comment: Thank You, but it doesn't solve my problem. Your measure counts orders per 'GreaterThen100' but I need a measure that counts every order between the date choosed in slicer.

Comment: Please try this,

    Total_Count  =  calculate('datasetname'[OrderID]),ALL(datasetname))